# Work with big numbers as array

Tags: php

I have to use big numbers for RSA so I use arrays:

```
$number1 = array(1234567, 7898765);
$number2 = array(9876543, 2123456);
```

How can I multiply them with a **fast** algorithm and calculate [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use either [gmp](http://php.net/gmp) or [bcmath](http://php.net/bcmath). These are php libraries designed for dealing with large numbers and computations.

Comment: **gmp** is great but i need to write code with my hands, so i'm looking for algorythm (:

Comment: I've put an algorithm you may wanna check out.

Answer (score 2):

**Algorithm**

To say that b is the modular inverse mod m of a is to say that

a * b = 1 (mod m)

for any integer a, there exist such an inverse b if and only if a and b are relatively prime. Using the extended euclidean algorithm we can find an x and y such that a * x + m * y = 1. From that is is apparent that a * x = 1 (mod m), therefore x is the modular inverse of a.

**Code**

I know you want it within PHP but I have C++ version maybe you can convert it into PHP later on.

```
int x = px;
int y = py;

//Setup initial variables
//Maintain throughout that ax * px + bx * py = x and that ay * px + by * py = y
int ax = 1;
int ay = 0;
int bx = 0;
int by = 1;

//Perform extended gcd
while(x)
{
    if(x <= y)
    {
        int m = y / x;
        y -= m * x;
        ay -= ax * m;
        by -= bx * m;
    }
    else
    {
        swap(x, y);
        swap(ax, ay);
        swap(bx, by);
    }
}

//you can assert that ay * px + by * py = y = gcd(px, py)
//you can assert that ax * px + bx * py = x = 0

//If we're taking the modular inverse of px (mod py), then for it to exist gcd(px, py) = 1
//If it does exist, it is given by ay (mod py)
int inverse = ay % py;
if(inverse < 0) inverse += py;
```

Comment: +1 for the modular inverse solution. Hopefully someone else will chime in with some advice about how to implement multiplication, division, and modulus with the extended precision ted is looking for.

Comment: @Braveyard, thanks for "modular multiplicative inverse" explanation, i know how it works the problem is to make it work with 'arrays number'